# Opacity from Highslide is not deleted when popup is closed

Tags: highslide

I have a popup tool from Highslide which works great.

But when I close the popup, the opacity isn't deleted and the whole site still stays dark grey.

Any idea what is going wrong?

http://www.familiekant.nl/toernooimaker/club/highslide.php

Click on the tab "Onderdelen" and than on the button "Selecteer" to see it in action.

Kind regards,

Arie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesnt wokr because you have undefined functions:

```
MakeRequest_onderdelen();
MakeRequest_banen();
```

in these lines

```
hs.Expander.prototype.onAfterClose = function() { 
  MakeRequest_onderdelen();
    MakeRequest_banen();  
}
```

Comment: Tnx alot! Indeed was MakeRequest_banen(); undefined ....... :-( but it works now like a charm ....... ;-)

Just another quick question, how do you discover this so I can check in the future for undefined functions myself?

I do use Firebug but I don't know how to use this Script tag to find errors in Javascript. Or do you use anther tool to debug javascript errors?

Kind regards,

Arie

Comment: I used console, which is avaiable in Firefox / Chrome developers tools.

Comment: Tnx, I look into the Javascript tab, assuming that you see there the errors also, but the Console tab does that a lot better!